# MongoDB 3.4 how increase speed aggregate query?

Tags: mongodb

I try to study MongoDB 3.4, htlp me please, i have a collection of documents:

```
{"title" : "Televisor № 1", "code" : 1, "attr" : [{"key" : "resolution", "value" : ["1920*1080"]}, {"key" : "network", "value" : ["wi-fi", "lan"]}, {"key" : "diagonal", "value" : ["27"]}]},
{"title" : "Televisor № 2", "code" : 2, "attr" : [{"key" : "resolution", "value" : ["1920*1080"]}, {"key" : "network", "value" : ["wi-fi", "lan"]}, {"key" : "diagonal", "value" : ["27"]}]},
{"title" : "Televisor № 3", "code" : 3, "attr" : [{"key" : "resolution", "value" : ["800*600"]}, {"key" : "network", "value" : ["wi-fi"]}, {"key" : "diagonal", "value" : ["24"]}]},
{"title" : "Televisor № 4", "code" : 4, "attr" : [{"key" : "resolution", "value" : ["800*600"]}, {"key" : "network", "value" : ["wi-fi", "lan"]}, {"key" : "diagonal", "value" : ["24"]}]},
{"title" : "Televisor № 5", "code" : 5, "attr" : [{"key" : "resolution", "value" : ["640*480"]}, {"key" : "network", "value" : ["wi-fi", "lan"]}, {"key" : "diagonal", "value" : ["18"]}]},
{"title" : "Televisor № 6", "code" : 6, "attr" : [{"key" : "resolution", "value" : ["640*480"]}, {"key" : "network", "value" : ["wi-fi", "lan"]}, {"key" : "diagonal", "value" : ["18"]}]},
```

I make a request to combine and count the number of attributes.
For example, this is used in the filters of Internet shop goods when the buyer selects a filter:

```
1920 * 1080 (2)
800 * 600 (0)
...

db.getCollection('testcollection').aggregate([
    {$match: {
    $and:[
        {"attr": {$elemMatch: {key: "network", value: {$in: ["4G","lan","wi-fi"]}}}},
        {"attr": {$elemMatch: {key: "resolution", value: {$in: ["1920*1080"]}}}},
    ]}},
    { "$unwind": "$attr" },
    { "$unwind": "$attr.value" },
    { "$project": {_id:null,key:"$attr.key", value:"$attr.value", count:{$sum:1}} },
    { "$group": {_id:{key:"$key",value:"$value"}, count:{$sum:"$count"}}},
])
```

I put in the collection of 50,000 TV sets and when I execute the query (in Robo3T), then its execution time is 0.5-0.6 seconds.
It seems to me too long? Can I somehow optimize it to improve the speed of getting the result?
I have an index only on the field '_id'

Comment: Add an index on `attr.key` at the very least. The `$project` is not doing you any favors and really should be merged into the `$group`, but the bulk of time will be in the `$match`. How many results are in the output? .5 seconds is not exactly slow

Comment: Query result set have 50000 unique values (because field 'diagonal' it's incremet). But application displays only 50 rows... And I tried to replace the string values (in attr.value) with numbers, but this did not have any effect.